# Bootstrap twitter 3.0 and knockoutjs validation

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

With Twitter Bootstrap the validation classes, e.g. `has-error` or `has-warning` need to be put on the wrapping `form-group` element in order to style the input element and it's label. But Knockout-Validation adds the class to the input element.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label">Input with error</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Is it possible to configure Knockout-Validation in a way that it adds the classes to the `div` and not the `input`?

Comment: Can you clarify your English? In particular, this sentence doesn't make sense: "Bootstrap wants to change the div instead of the input element." Wants to change the div? What div? And in what way? What does this have to do with input elements?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The answer by thebringking doesn't get you all the way there. You'll also need to specify the `errorMessageClass` and `decorateInputElement` options.

```js
ko.validation.init({
  errorElementClass: 'has-error',
  errorMessageClass: 'help-block',
  decorateInputElement: true
});

var viewModel = ko.validatedObservable({
  name: ko.observable().extend({
    required: true
  }),
  email: ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    email: true
  }),
  submit: function() {

    if (!this.isValid()) {
      this.errors.showAllMessages();
    } else {
      alert('good job');
    }
  }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: name">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="name">Name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="textInput: name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: email">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="textInput: email" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The option is now called decorateInputElement. See https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Thanks!  For anyone trying similar, the init function needs to be ran outside of a viewmodel/before starting binds

Answer (score 5):

You could extend knockout validation core like this:

```
var init = ko.bindingHandlers['validationCore'].init;
ko.bindingHandlers['validationCore'].init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    var config = ko.validation.utils.getConfigOptions(element);
    // if requested, add binding to decorate element
    if (config.decorateInputElement && ko.validation.utils.isValidatable(valueAccessor())) {
        var parent = $(element).parents(".form-group");
        if (parent.length) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(parent[0], { validationElement: valueAccessor() });
        }
    }
};
```

This code makes the parent form-group be decorated with the same class as the input.

Comment: Thanks, just needed to change `config.decorateElement` to `config.decorateInputElement` to match with current version.

Comment: This is a really neat solution, and also led me to the source of a problem I was having that others might also encounter - where I was using one custom binding to add the wrapper elements (for Material Design Lite) and also had a value/textInput binding. The order, as seems obvious now, is important as you need the wrapper element to be added before the validation init fires - so make sure your value/textInput binding is after any custom binding to add the wrapper element.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the "validationElement" binding handler on the bootstrap form div-

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: someObservable">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
</div>
```

Then you would set the [configuration](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration) for the knockout validation plugin to use the bootstrap error class of "has-error".

```
ko.validation.init({errorElementClass:'has-error'})
```

This is the way I do it in our tool.